# Selection Sort vs Quicksort for Small Data

Tags: java, sorting

I know that quicksort is the fastest sorting algorithm at the moment. If I have a small dataset of 7 or 10 terms, will selection sort work better than quicksort or the other way around?

Comment: In any case, you wouldn't care, and you would use the built-in Java sort method anyway. Any algorithm will be fast enough to sort 10 terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> quicksort is the fastest sorting algorithm at the moment

This is not correct. E.g. counting sort is faster. Quicksort has O(n*logn), CountingSort has O(n).

> If I have a small dataset of 7 or 10 terms, will selection sort work
>   better than quicksort or the other way around?

According to the usage - yes. Time complexity is worse for SelectionSort, but it is more simple. You should not shuffle the collection at the beginning and so on. For **small** data you could choose any simpliest sorting algorithm and do not worry about performance.

Comment: "For small data you could choose any simpliest sorting algorithm and do not worry about performance." <---- this